# Provider hosted app installation on test environment

Tags: app, provider-hosted-app

I need to publish and install provider hosted app on app catalog site on test environment.

I followed the procedure by registering app using

```
http://mytestserver.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx
```

and published app , used Client Id and self signed certificate details while Publishing.

Next when I installed app on test and tried to run it I get below error:

> This page can't be displayed
>
> Make sure the web address `https://mytestserver.com` is correct.
>
> Look for the page with your search engine.
>
> Refresh the page in a few minutes.
>
> Make sure TLS and SSL protocols are enabled. Go to Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Settings > Security

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I m assuming what you trying to achieve here is -
**Office 365 + App in Azure Websites**

If so there is few steps that you need to follow before you can successfully deploy Provider Hosted App -

1. Make sure you have "Apps for Office and SharePoint Toolkit" installed in your project, use nuget package manager for it.
2. Then follow this blog [deploying-sp2013-provider-hosted](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/07/deploying-sp2013-provider-hosted.html) by Chris O'Brien